# code gives error 1004 application defined or object defined error

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, filter

I'm still inexperienced in VBA and currently I am trying to make a loop to search for a string within an array, and paste it in another cell as follows:

```
Dim PDD As Worksheet
Dim SumSheet1 As Worksheet
Set PDD = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Patient Demographics-Diagnosis")

PDD.Range("BM" & copystartrow & ":BM" & PDDlastrow).Copy
SumSheet1.Range("C" & pastestartrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Dim complications_all As String
complications_all = SumSheet1.Range("C" & pastestartrow).Value

Dim newvar1 As String
newvar1 = "Urinary calculus, unspecified"

Dim newvarr1

Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("A:A")

    newvarr1 = Filter(Split(complications_all, ";"), newvar1, True, vbBinaryCompare)
    If Len(Join(newvarr1, ",")) > 0 Then
        SumSheet1.Cells(pasterownum, "E").Value = newvar1
    End If

Next c
```

But I am getting the "error 1004 application defined or object defined error" error in the following line

```
SumSheet1.Cells(pasterownum, "E").Value = newvar1
```

Could anyone help explain this error to me and why it is showing up? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not seeing that line in your code. I see one similar to it... but...

Comment: The line you say you are getting the error does not appear in your code. The most similar one is `SumSheet1.Cells(pasterownum, "E").Value = newvar1` but it's not the same. You do not show how you assign variables. And probably you should post what `Filter` does because I think it's not a native VBA function. Anyways, you defined `c` as range and then you do `Cells(c, "E")`. In that case, `Cells(c, "E")` is expecting a number value, not a range object.

Comment: sorry, made a typo there while copying, changed c -> pasterownum

Comment: what is the value of `pasterownum` when the error arises?

Comment: @Ike That's incorrect. `Cells` object admits (numeric, string) notation. IF you do something like `Cells(3, "B").Value = "Hello world"` it will work properly. So `SumSheet1.Cells(pasterownum, "E")` should work as long as `pasterownum` has a correct numeric value

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns: ok - I will delete the comment - I always try to use either row/cell - or A1 logic  - because of "cleanness" - propably that's why I thought, a mixed variant is not allowed.

Comment: @Ike I always do like you say. Actually, I discovered on SO that `Cells` admit (numeric, string) notation because I did not know it! Anyways, I prefer like you say and work on A1 notation :)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns how would you code it if i want the row number to be respective? like for example when its looping on row 1, row 1's value will be pasted in E1; when its on row 2, row 2's value will be pasted into E2 and so on

Comment: According to your code, you are looping through column A (full column A, that's a lot!!!!) Probably what you want is `SumSheet1.Cells(c.row, "E").Value = newvar1` but you should look here on Stack Overflow about looping through columns and getting last non blank row.

Comment: yeahhhh cause my data base will be huge so im just looping until the last entered cell for column A